# Статические блоки инициализации

Tags: java, static, инициализация

В нижеприведенном коде есть 2 статических блока, почему компилятор не считает за ошибку то, что в первом блоке не указан тип данных у `i`?
При этом, если при инициализации `i = 0` убрать тип данных будет ошибка, и если указать тип данных только во втором блоке тоже будет ошибка.

```java
public class Test {
    
    static {
        i = 10;
    }
    
    static int i = 0;

    static {
        ++i;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Компилятор сначала обработает *объявление* статической переменной, а уже потом будут выполнены блоки статической инициализации и/или присваивания статической переменной в порядке их определения в коде.  В частности, это приведёт к тому, что присваивание 10 в первом блоке будет утеряно.

Порядок таков:

1. Объявляется статическая переменная `i`.
2. Выполняется первый блок статической инициализации `static {i = 10;}`
3. Выполняется присваивание при объявлении переменной `static int i = 0`
4. Выполняется второй блок статической инициализации `static {++i; // 1}`

Но если бы вы попытались обратиться в первом блоке статической инициализации к переменной (например, `System.out.println(i);`), *тогда* возникла бы ошибка компиляции, связанная с обращением к неопределённой переменной.

```java
static {
    System.out.println("1st block in: i=" + i);  // error: illegal forward reference
    i = 10;
    System.out.println("1st block out: i=" + i); // error: illegal forward reference
}

static int i = 0;
```

См. [Which cases allow forward referencing in static initializer blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626337/)

---

> *При этом, если при инициализации `i = 0` убрать тип данных будет ошибка,*

Разумеется, тогда у вас получается *неправильно объявленная* статическая переменная (не указан тип).

> *и если указать тип данных только во втором блоке тоже будет ошибка.*

В таком случае вы объявляете *локальную переменную* внутри блока статической инициализации, изменения в которой не повлияют на значение переменной класса.

Модифицированный пример:

```java
static {
    int i = 10;
    System.out.println("1st block out: i=" + i); // локальная переменная блока 1
}

static int i = 5;

static {
    System.out.println("2nd block in: i=" + i);  // переменная класса
    int i = 20;
    System.out.println("2nd block out: i=" + i); // локальная переменная блока 2
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Результат:

```
1st block out: i=10
2nd block in: i=5
2nd block out: i=20
5
```